# why do I have to press enter twice for each string I enter?

Tags: c, string, buffer

This is the code:

```
void inserisciStringa(int dim, char *i) {
    int men = 1;
    do {
        if (scanf("%[^\n]s", i) == 1) {
            svuotaBuffer();               // I think this is the problem
            int len = checkStrLen(men, dim, i);
            int num = checkNumbers(len, i);
            if (len && num)
                break;
        }
        printf("\nError");
        printf("\nTry again: ");
    } while (1);
}

int checkStrLen(int min, int max, char *s) {
    int len = strlen(s);
    if (len >= min && len <= max)
        return len;
    else
        return 0;
}

int checkNumbers(int len, char *s) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9') {
            printf("\nNot Numbers");
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

void svuotaBuffer() {
    char c;
    do {
        c = getchar();
    } while(c != '\n');
}
```

Every time I have to insert a string I am forced to press enter twice because of the `svuotaBuffer()`.
But if I remove it, I have infinite cycles.
Can I fix it somehow? I've noticed that it doesn't always do this, but it's a very annoying problem

Comment: @user3121023 Probably the problem is that I was using a 'svuotaBuffer()' even after calling the function

Comment: Please change `scanf("%[^\n]s", i)` to `scanf(" %[^\n]", i)` which has two changes: added space, removed s. And delete the kludge `svuotaBuffer();` that's the job of the added space.

Comment: You cannot structure your scanf loop like that.  If you write `do { if( scanf(...) == 1 ) break; } while(1);` you run the very real possibility of an infinite loop in which scanf repeatedly attempts to process the same data and never makes any progress on the input stream.

Comment: @WeatherVane the added space clear the buffer only from spaces  the `svoutaBuffer()` clear the buffer from anything till a `\n` is encountered. They are not exactly the same thing.

Comment: @Davide the space filters all leading whitespace in the buffer, no matter how much, regardless of whether there is any. That makes `%[]` and `%c` behave like other format specs which automatically do that. I called it a kludge for a reason. If there might be unwanted non-whitespace stuff to clear, it's better to use `fgets()` instead of `scanf()` and be done with it.

Comment: ... there is only partial code shown. If there has been a previous use of `scanf()` leaving a newline in the buffer, the buffer clearance kludge here won't help. It's better to use `scanf()` the way it was intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem come from `scanf()`, a very tricky function:

- first the format string `"%[^\n]s"` is incorrect, it should be just `"%[^\n]"` as the trailing `s` is not the same as `%s`, it means match an `s` in the input stream, which cannot happen there as the only pending character after the previous conversion is `\n` or end-of-file.
- your conversion is risky because you cannot tell `scanf()` how many characters to store into the destination array. Any sufficient long input line will cause undefined behavior.
- after a successful conversion, the newline will be left pending in the input stream. This newline must be read before attempting to read the next line with `scanf()`. Otherwise `scanf()` will fail because `%[^\n]` cannot convert an empty string.
- after a failed conversion, which is what happens the second time, `svuotaBuffer()` must also be called to get rid of the pending newline.

Also note these issues:

- `svuotaBuffer()` has a problem too: `c` should have type `int` and you must check for `EOF` to avoid an infinite loop at end of file. Here is a corrected version:

  ```
  int svuotaBuffer(void) {
     int c;
     while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
         continue;
     return c;    // allow the caller to test for end-of-file.
  }
  ```
- the function `checkNumbers` should return `1` if the loop completes.
- it is **very confusing** to name a `char *` `i`.

Here is a modified version:

```
int checkStrLen(int min, int max, char *s) {
    int len = strlen(s);
    if (len >= min && len <= max)
        return len;
    else
        return 0;
}

int checkNumbers(int len, char *s) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9') {
            printf("\nNot Numbers");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int svuotaBuffer(void) {
   int c;
   while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
       continue;
   return c;    // allow the caller to test for end-of-file.
}

int inserisciStringa(int dim, char *dest) {
    int men = 1;
    for (;;) {
        if (scanf("%[^\n]", dest) == 1) {
            svuotaBuffer();  // read the ending newline if any
            if (checkStrLen(men, dim, dest) && checkNumbers(len, dest))
                return 0;
        }
        if (svuotaBuffer() == EOF) {
            printf("\nUnexpected end of file\n");
            return -1;  // report failure to the caller.
        }
        printf("\nError");
        printf("\nTry again: ");
    }
}
```

You should really use `fgets()` for this task. Here is a modified version:

```
int inserisciStringa(int dim, char *dest) {
    int men = 1;
    int len;
    for (;;) {
        if (!fgets(dest, dim, stdin)) {
            printf("\nUnexpected end of file\n");
            return -1;  // report end of file failure to the caller.
        }
        len = strlen(dest);
        if (len > 0 && dest[len - 1] == '\n')
            dest[--len] == '\0';  // strip the trailing newline
        if (len < men) {
            printf("\nError: line too short");
        } else
        if (len < dim - 1) {
            if (checkNumbers(len, dest))
                return 0;
            printf("\nError: string has digits");
        } else {
            printf("\nError: line too long");
            svuotaBuffer();
        }
        printf("\nTry again: ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
        int men=1;
        do {
            if (scanf("%[^\n]s", i) == 1) {
                svuotaBuffer();                        //I think this is the problem
                int len = checkStrLen(men, dim, i);
                int num = checkNumbers(len,i);
                if (len && num) break;
            }
            printf("\nError");
            printf("\nTry again: ");
        } while(1);
```

Could be implemented in a simpler way, eg, allowing you to eliminate `svuotaBuffer`, et. al.:

```
   ....
    char line[80] = {0};
    int num = 0, len = 0;

    fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
    while(line[0] != '\n'))
    {
        line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = 0;//eliminate newline
        len = strlen(line);//check line length
        num = checkNumbers(len,i); 
        //do other things, i.e. parse and/or store line in output file, ...?
        fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
    }


    ....
```